# unable to save marathi language value from spinner to mysql database using android code

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xml

In `android app` I have `spinner` which `populate marathi values` from `.xml file`

Now I have one `insert.php` which will `insert values from spinner to mysql table`.

But i get runtime exception :(
`Null.exception`

`strings.xml`

```
 <string-array name="problems">
     <item>सार्वजनिक पाळणा घर</item>
        <item>बस सेवा</item>
        <item>सार्वजनिक अभ्यासिका</item>
        <item>जॉगीग पार्क</item>        
    </string-array>
```

`input_box.xml`

```
  <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_problems"
            android:entries="@array/problems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
             />
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
 final Spinner problems = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
String myvalue = String.valueOf(problems
.getSelectedItem());


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",myval));       

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://wwwd.emo.com/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();               

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();         

        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
                new DialogTask().execute("Success");
                }
            else
            {
                new DialogTask().execute("Failure");
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your stack trace. We can use that to help determine what your problem is. You've only just told us its a `NullPointerException`. Before that, you only said it was a runtime error. Stack traces are a must-have for Java questions which are about errors.

Comment: `I'm really very new to android development.`
I just found that I'm unable to get any current selected value from spinner I just get NullPointerExceptionnothing else :(

I used following code to get current selected value from spinner

 `final Spinner problems = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
String myvalue = String.valueOf(problems.getSelectedItem());`

will update question with screenshot stacktrace 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks you have not implemented the spinner click listener and are retrieving values incorrectly.